# Mount TV above baseboard heater

Tags: heater, television

I need to mount my tv on a wall, or maybe just leave it on the stand, but the only wall that works has a baseboard heater on it.

I've seen other questions about TVs over fireplaces, but my TV is going to be at least 24" above the heater (the stuff in the entertainment center under it, though...).  Should I rig some sort of shelf just above the heater?  For when winter finally gets here.

Comment: The rule of thumb to remember is that for every 18 degrees F, the lifetime of semiconductors is cut in half.    With a good warranty covering manufacturing defects you might get a new one after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to check the actual maximum heat coming off of the baseboard heater, and compare that with the operating temperatures of your TV in the manual.

I will admit, if the baseboard heater is at the baseboard, I'd imagine you'd mount the TV much higher than two feet off the floor? If not, I think you may be a bit close.

Comment: Bottom of the TV is two feet above the baseboard, which puts it at 32" off the floor (for now - although I think I've discovered it might be mounted _too high_ for a good viewing angle).  I'm still mulling my options, but I'm leaning somewhat towards removing the heater come winter (wall is shared with neighbor).